# What kind of wav or wave sound data format is required in vosk nodejs library for speech recognition?

Tags: node.js, speech-recognition, wav, wave, vosk

[Vosk](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/) is a speech recognition framework. In the provided samples, they use a wav recorded directly from microphone (native) and it works

- [python sample](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/master/python/test/transcribe_scp.py)
- [nodejs sample](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/master/nodejs/demo/test_microphone.js)

My requirement is to get the sound from a stream (socket) instead of local microphone but vosk is not detecting the buffer as valid wav file.

**rec.acceptWaveform returns [true] when buffer comes from microphone**

```
const rec = new vosk.Recognizer
var mic = require("mic");
var micInstance = mic({...});

micInputStream.on('data', async (buffer) => {    
    if (rec.acceptWaveform(buffer)){
      console.log("rec.result():", rec.result())
```

**rec.acceptWaveform returns [false] when buffer comes from socket client**

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, { maxHttpBufferSize: 1e7 })
rec = new vosk.Recognizer({model: model, sampleRate: sampleRate});  
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('send-audio', async function (data) {
    console.log("received:", data)
    if(rec.acceptWaveform(data)){
      console.log("rec.acceptWaveform:", true)
      console.log("rec.result():", rec.result())
    }else{
      console.log("rec.acceptWaveform:", false)
    }
```

### Attempts and Research

- According to the [nodejs vosk library](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/aba84973b188bac259b2914cbb1455c6c68dd9b6/nodejs/index.js#L327), buffer should be an audio data in PCM 16-bit mono format
- I'm using this nodejs library to inspect the wave buffer called [wavefile](https://github.com/rochars/wavefile)
- The buffer received from socket can be read as wav file using the library **wavefile**. The wave details confirms that is a valid wave file, but for vosk is not a wave format. I also can save it directly as file and audacity is able to read it.

  - [image]
- The buffer received directly from microphone **cannot** be read with **wavefile** library but **for vosk is a valid wave format**. If I save the buffer as file, using audacity the wave file is not valid

  - [image]
- I also tried sending only the [data section bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVd2n.png) without success.
- I raised 02 issues

  - https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/issues/1504
  - https://github.com/rochars/wavefile/issues/42
- I will try with python just to test if it is a bug with wave from socket clients.

### Question

What kind of wav or wave data format is required in vosk nodejs library for speech recognition?

### Reproducible sample

I create a reproducible source code:

https://github.com/jrichardsz/nodejs-wav-vosk-transcription